# Changing Background color on NSAttributedString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsattributedstring

I just wanted to know how could i change the background color of an NSAttributedString, i can see the background being white all the time, but i want to make it black.

Is that possible?? Many thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you want NSBackgroundColorAttributeName. Such as:

```
[mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:selectedRange];
```

Comment: Works for me. iOS is the only thing I've used it with.

Comment: What if I want to put a background color only the text, words and spaces, without putting bg color on the new line? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For Swift:

```
attributedString.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: yourColor, range: NSMakeRange(0, tillLocation))
```

Helpful link - [Different way to attribute a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32269975/3322147)

Answer (score 0):

The best plan would really be to draw the string on a view with a black background.

Comment: I found out that i wanted to change the color for the NSAttributedStringView and not the string :) silly me... Thanks!