# NSAttributedString - What is the attribute to be used for text background color?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background-color, nsattributedstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSBackgroundColorAttributeName-like attribute in NSAttributedString on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707906/nsbackgroundcolorattributename-like-attribute-in-nsattributedstring-on-ios)

I am trying to set the text background color in my attributed string.
What is the attribute that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NSBackgroundColorAttributeName](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSBackgroundColorAttributeName)

Comment: That's only available in OSX, I need to use it on iPhone

Comment: Wow, interesting. In that case, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424003/changing-background-color-on-nsattributedstring).

Comment: +1, Added to iOS in iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the color of `NSAttributedStringView`

Comment: I want different background colors for different portion of text

Comment: @aryaxt: Then you want to following this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707906/nsbackgroundcolorattributename-like-attribute-in-nsattributedstring-on-ios