# CATextLayer doesn't draw NSAttributedString background color

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have CATextLayer and want to set background color to part of the string. But setting background color to attributed string (NSBackgroundColorAttributeName) doesn't have any effect. Other attributes, such as foreground color, are applied correctly.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Some Text"] autorelease];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSColor yellowColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                            [NSColor redColor], NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, nil];

[str setAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];

textLayer.string = str;
```

First three symbols are drawn in yellow color, but background won't change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the `CATextLayer` class uses the `CoreText` API for its rendering. The `CoreText` API are very low-level and only support a subset of the `NSAttributedString` attributes. Unfortunately, the `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` is not one of those. You have to deal with it manually (see [this SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707906/nsbackgroundcolorattributename-like-attribute-in-nsattributedstring-on-ios)).