# CATextLayer NSBackGroundColorAttributeName is there a way to make it works?

Tags: swift, calayer, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to make a `CATextLayer` accept `NSBackGroundColorAttributeName` the attribute in an attributed string?

```
   let mutableAttributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text , attributes: [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor(),
            NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(),
            NSFontAttributeName :UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
            ])
    let textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true
    textLayer.string = mutableAttributed
    textLayer.bounds.size = CGSizeMake(200,200)
```

But it simply doesn't work, reading Stack I've found a reasonable  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174980/catextlayer-doesnt-draw-nsattributedstring-background-color) but is pretty old, and it doesn't seems to be fully clear, if from iOS6 it should support it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you pointed to is right. CATextLayer is very primitive and doesn't support this feature. Luckily, there is no need to use core text either; you can now use TextKit and just draw the string directly (and don't use CATextLayer at all).

```
class MyTextLayer : CALayer {
    @NSCopying var string : NSAttributedString?

    override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext) {
        super.drawInContext(ctx)
        UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)
        string?.drawWithRect(self.bounds,
            options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to assemble code from the original one, of course in the original I was setting the right property. I've update the answer. Thanks

Comment: Added code showing how to build a CALayer that draws its own attributed text.

Comment: Actually I can' t use a normal TextKit View, because I'm adding layers over a video composition. As far as I remember Apple explicitly say to do not use UIView's layer.
Now I'm thinking to use your code or just enumerating string attributes, to set just the layer background. Many thanks

Comment: The point is this. Back in the CATextLayer days, you had to use CoreText (and NSAttributedString was extremely hard to use; it wasn't really a native type on iOS). But an NSAttributedString nowadays knows how to draw itself (as my code shows). When it does that, you're using TextKit; to put another way, TextKit is the innovation that makes this possible, and that didn't happen until after the discussion you were looking at before.