# Text selected without showing the pins

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to programmatically select a text without showing the pins at the beginning and at the end of the selected text?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Although you should be more precise, I presume you just want to highlight some parts of the text with a background color. Therefore you can use `NSAttributedString`.

You can look up how to create an attributed String [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666515/how-do-i-make-an-attributed-string-using-swift) and how to use background color on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424003/changing-background-color-on-nsattributedstring).

Comment: The behaviour is not the same as selecting a text with cursor